# Java help needed for a code like Autocorrect

Tags: java, android, matcher, autocorrect

I am writing a program which is the opposite of Auto Correct. The logic is that the user enters a sentence, when a button is pressed, the grammatical opposite of the sentence entered by the user should be displayed. I am roughly able to get the code. I used the matcher logic.But i am not able to get the desired output. I am linking the code with this question. Can anyone help me please?

```
imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String input = editText.getText().toString();
                String store = input;
                String store1 [] = store.split(" ");
                String correct[] = {"is","shall","this","can","will"};
                String wrong [] = {"was","should","that","could","would"};
                String output = "";
                for (int i=0;i<store1.length;i++) {
                    for(int j=0;j<correct.length;j++){
                        if(store1[i].matches(correct[j])) {
                            output = input.replace(store1[i], wrong[j]);


                            //store1[i] = wrong[j];
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            input.replace(store1[i], store1[i]);
                            //store1[i] = store1[i];
                        }

                    }
                mTextView.setText(output);

            }
        }});
```

Comment: try using `equalsIgnoreCase` instead of `matches`. because `matches` is for regex pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at your code, I've found some **redundancy** and **unused variable.** Shown as below.

```
 String store = input;
 String store1 [] = store.split(" ");
```

As shown below, I did some cleanup for you and implement your logic using Map interface. The wrong value must be the Key of the map so that we can easily determine is the word a wrong value using Map.containKeys(word). If key is found then we concatenate the output variable with the correct word.

```
    String input = editText.getText().toString().split(" ");

    Map<String, String> pairs = new HashMap<>();
    pairs.put("is", "was");
    pairs.put("shall", "should");
    pairs.put("this", "that");
    pairs.put("can", "could");
    pairs.put("will", "would");

    String output = "";

    for (String word : input) {
        if (pairs.containsKey(word)) {
            output = output + pairs.get(word) + " ";
        } else {
            output = output + word + " ";
        }
    }

    mTextView.setText(output.trim());
```

Comment: Thank you:) But this is what i get:

Comment: Example: Input: This is awesome, Output: Thisisawesome. I want the output to be : This was awesome

Comment: @R.ven what if the input is This was awesome? Output will be This was awesome? Am i right?